# Count the assocations in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in python:

```
x=[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],['apple', 'banana'],['banana', 'carrot']]
```

I want to know the number of times two items are associated in an array.

My output would be like:

```
{['apple', 'banana']: 2, ['banana', 'carrot']: 2, ['apple', 'carrot']: 1}
```

I know how to count the occurrences of an item in a list of lists, but not too sure how to add a counter for the association of occurrences to the mix.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your output would have to have key as tuple, since lists are not hashable

Comment: The Brute-Force way would be: For each two elements of each list, insert it in the dictionary as a tuple (maybe sort the tuple to have the same order always) and increment the count.

Comment: does the order matter of the two items? can an item be paired with itself? i feel you could provide a few more complex examples to clarify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with itertools and collections (both of which are in the standard library):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

x=[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],['apple', 'banana'],['banana', 'carrot']]
print(Counter(combo for sublist in x for combo in combinations(sublist , 2)))
# Counter({('apple', 'banana'): 2, ('banana', 'carrot'): 2, ('apple', 'carrot'): 1})
```

Here, whenever two items exist in one of the sublists, `combinations` spits them out as a pair, then `Counter` counts this pair.